# Excel VBA, Parsing Response from a HTTP request

Tags: json, vba, excel

This feels like it should be really simple but I'm a bit stuck. I want to access an API url using Excel VBA. The API gives me a very simple JSON response containing a load id which is used as a parameter in the calling of another API, the other API isn't a problem because I can get the response in either XML or CSV and parse it into Excel.

API Response:
{"loadid":"1234567890"}

All I need to extract from this response is the number "1234567890".

This is what I've tried so far:

```
Sub getLoadID()

Dim loadID As String
Dim loadIDUrl As String
loadIDUrl = "blah blah"

proxyServer = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

Set httpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttprequest.5.1")

httpReq.Open "GET", loadIDUrl, False

httpReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
httpReq.setProxy 2, proxyServer, ""
httpReq.setTimeouts -1, -1, -1, -1
httpReq.send request

httpReq.ResponseText = loadID
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = loadID

End Sub
```

I've tried to put the whole string into a cell just to make sure that Excel is able to obtain the string from the response but going forward will just be happy to store the value as a variable and not write it to the sheet.

The above code runs with no errors, I just don't get the string in cell A2...

Every time I've searched about parsing JSON using Excel VBA everyone recommends to use external libraries but I'm trying to do this at work so I can't use the external libraries.

Cheers

Comment: `loadId = httpReq.ResponseText` no? instead of how you have it?

Comment: Okay... thank you... that was easy *face palm*